# PHP - Download image from browser?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm writing a little program that pulls information from a website and displays it.  The resultant page shows a grid of thumbnail images that click through to a large (original) version of the same image:

```
<?php 
   for ($x=0; $x < $imgCount; $x++) {
   echo '<a class="thumbnail-link" href="' . $finalImageArray[$x] . '">';
   echo $imgs[$x];
   echo '</a>';
   }
?>

$imgCount is the number of thumbnail images
$imgs --> Array of <img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/each/thumbnail-img.jpg" />
$finalImageArray --> Array of http://www.example.com/path/to/original/large-img.jpg
```

Right now, I click-through the thumbnail to the large image, then right-click, 'save image as'.  I was wondering if it was possible to simplify this process, whereby clicking the thumbnail triggers the download of the larger image.

Comment: right-click, "save link target as" instead of "save image as"?

Comment: interesting - 'save target as' when clicked on the thumbnail does exactly what I want...is there a PHP function that emulates that?

Comment: even if it is possible - do not do this, do not override default right click action

Comment: no. nothing you can do in the html will force a download. you'd need to serve up the pictures via a php script with a `content-disposition: attachment` to force the download.

Comment: @Lashane no intention of overriding the right-click, I just want to trigger the file download on left-click (precisely what right-click + 'save target as' does)

Comment: @TheNally then you should serve your images with content-disposition as MarcB suggested

Comment: @MarcB just read the PHP documentation - this looks great.  Not 100% sure how to implement it yet. I'll try it out and get back if I'm stuck - thanks!

Comment: @MarcB - you were right. 'content-disposition: attachment' was the right way to go.  I'm having separate issues regarding image encoding/decoding, but feel free to answer the question or I can answer it myself.  I'll deal with those issues in a separate question.  Thanks for the help.